# Why Angular 2 imports from relative node_modules rather than mapped node_modules?

Tags: angular, webstorm

I think this is the problem with WebStorm and not core Angular problem.
This is how it imports when I press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> and then when I open the webpage it says 404 for that `node_module`.

```
import {Router} from "../../../../node_modules/@angular/router/src/router";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "../../../../node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_state";
```

Before it used to import like this, which is right:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
```

It used to work normal but now it doesn't imports from the mapped files in `system.config.js`. I don't know why this happened. I tried to change diff things in `system.config.js` and `tsconfig.json`. Don't know if it is related to that.

My System.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */

(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-server': 'npm:@angular/platform-server/bundles/platform-server.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',


      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'ng2-translate/ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js',
      'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.umd.js',
      'primeng':                   'npm:primeng'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      primeng: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
    }
  });
})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings",
      "aot"
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: please attach a screenshot of File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import page

Comment: I have added the sdreenshot.

Comment: which ide version do you use? Which "@angular/router" version do you use? Please, check that "node_modules/@angular/router/index.d.ts" file exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projectName.iml file in the .idea directory I had a line

`<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/node_modules" />`

which seemed to be causing the issue for me, deleted it and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me helped using **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart** and removing files in .idea (just leave it empty). After that imports works fine for me.